# Calculating percentage based on an average percentage

Tags: percentages

This is a typical question a student at any Business School have to deal with during the test. Could you please give me insight on how to solve it. What area of study should I invest in?

> A student has obtained an average of 47% across the seven subjects
>   that he has taken so far.
>
> When he takes his eighth and final subject what mark must he obtain to
>   ensure that his overall mark is 50%?

I apologize if the question below has the wrong tag.

Comment: His total percentage on the seven subjects taken so far must be $7\times 47\%=329\%$. He needs his total percentage after the 8th paper to be $8\times 50\%=400\%$, so me must get at least $71\%$ on the final paper. To answer your question, I need to know what part of that seems hard to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially we have
$$\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_7}{7}=0.47$$
Which implies that
$$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_7=7\times 0.47=3.29$$
Therefore 
$$\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_8}{8}=0.50$$
$$\frac{3.29+x_8}{8}=0.50$$
$$3.29+x_8=8\times 0.50$$
$$3.29+x_8=4$$
$$x_8=4-3.29=0.71$$
As far as what you should study to solve this, I'd say the arithmetic mean, algebra and of course percentages.

Comment: Thanks. Crystal clear explanation :)